# Issue with OAUTH consent screen

Tags: google-oauth

I am trying to get an oauth 2.0 client id but I am redirected to the oauth consent screen. However the google oauth consent screen is giving me errors when I try to save my application name. I left the other fields blank as I was guided my my tutor to only fill up the application name and email field. I am having issues configuring the oauth consent screen. I keep getting an error that says

`“the request failed because changes to one of the field of the resource is not supported.”`

[image: screenshot of error message]

Its my first time using google oauth and I did everything my tutor did in the udemy course but I hit the save button, I get this same error all day! Please check my screenshots for more details. Any help will be appreciated..

[image: screenshot of the fields I filled and the ones left blank]

Comment: I'm facing this problem too. I found information about this in the known issues tab on the support screen of GCP. https://imgur.com/a/fdJD0m3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an ongoing outage issue with Oauth Client Id Creation, you can see the banner here https://status.cloud.google.com/

[Outage Banner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ip2FO.png)

Should be fixed soon, hopefully!

Answer (score 3):

try a unique name for your app
I had the same issue and it worked for me

Comment: Solved it for me. Sometimes the solution is very short.

Answer (score 0):

If you created an api key before the redirection to the oauth consent screen for the app you want to integrate google sign in with, try adding the api key to the scope for google apis on the consent screen This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It was a google server issue. I think their server was down at that particular time I was having the issue because the next day I tried it without doing anything different and it worked seamlessly.